# Adding records through form and subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two tables with the following information.

```
    PatientTestData     [ ID, PatientID, TestDate, PrimaryTestID ]
    PatientTestResults  [ PatientTestDataID, SubTestID, Result ]
```

Then there is a form with a subform with the following relevant information.

```
MainForm     [  TestDataID, TestDate, PatientID, PrimaryTestID  ]
subform      [  PrimaryTestID, PatientTestDataID, SubTestID, Result  ]
```

The subform is filtered with “PrimaryTestID” field from the main form and results are manually being entered in the Result field to be be added to the table PatientTestResults.

I am using the following code to update the fields to the tables.

```
Private Sub Update_Click()
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("PatientTestResults")
    rs.AddNew
    rs!SubTestID = Me.frm_TestResults!ID
    rs!Result = Me.frm_TestResults!Result
    rs!PatientTestDataID = Me.ID.Value
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
    rs.Clone
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
End Sub
```

[image: But click here to see the image of the result in the table PatientTestResults]

I’ve got two problems

1. PatientTestDataID field value should be there in each row of the table.
2. The row in which PatientTestDataID field value occurs is repeated in the table.

Comment: Why do you MoveNext and Clone?

Comment: Why db.Close? Where is this code being called from (I am assuming the main form)? - I am not familiar with the form syntax `Me.frm_TestResults!ID` which should be something like `Me.frm_TestResults.TextBox1.Text`.

Comment: If forms and controls are bound to data source, don't need code. Data entered is passed directly to table. Data is committed when 1) move to another record or 2) close table/query/form or 3) run code to explicitly save record. If forms are bound then you are doing double input with the manual entry and the code. If forms are bound, have you set Master/Child Links properties of the subform container control?

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your kind answer and precious time.                  
    I removed the whole code                                                            
    rs.MoveNext
    rs.Clone
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close                                                                                                                 
    but it is still doing the same. And yes, forms subform is not bound because data is coming from a query and going to some other tables. So i have to use code. But it is still not working. Still the same problem.